# Integration of docusignapi via PHP CURL issue : error calling webservice, status is:0

Tags: php, rest, curl, docusignapi

Good Day i'm new to this docusignapi integration via PHP curl and i want to try this integration. I've copy the code below from http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/requestSignatureFromDocument and hoping i can easily test and understand how the integration works. But unfortunately an error always occur "error calling webservice, status is:0". I've tried other work around like changing the header format from XML to JSON but the error still shows up. Please help.

```
    // Input your info here:
$integratorKey = 'XXXX-9999X9XX-X999-9999-99X9-9X9999X9XX9X';
$email = 'name@domain.com';
$password = 'samplepassword';
$name = 'Sender Full Name';

// construct the authentication header:
$header = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" . $email . "</Username><Password>" . $password . "</Password><IntegratorKey>" . $integratorKey . "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// STEP 1 - Login (to retrieve baseUrl and accountId)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
$curl = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));
print_r(curl_getinfo($curl));
echo "<br/>";
$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $status != 200 ) {
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status;
    exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$accountId = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["accountId"];
$baseUrl = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["baseUrl"];
curl_close($curl);

//--- display results
echo "\naccountId = " . $accountId . "\nbaseUrl = " . $baseUrl . "\n";

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // STEP 2 - Create an envelope with one recipient, one tab, and one document and send
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $data = array (
    "emailBlurb" => "This comes from PHP",
    "emailSubject" => "API Signature Request",
    "documents" => array(array( "documentId" => "1", "name" => "testDS.pdf")),
    "recipients" => array( "signers" => array(
            array(      "email" => $email,
                        "name" => $name,
                        "recipientId" => "1",
                        "tabs" => array(
                                "signHereTabs" => array(
                                        array(
                                            "xPosition" => "100",
                                            "yPosition" => "100",
                                            "documentId" => "1",
                                            "pageNumber" => "1"
                                         )
                                    )
                            )
                    )
            )
    ),
"status" => "sent");  
$data_string = json_encode($data);  

$file_contents = file_get_contents("testDS.pdf");

$requestBody = "\r\n"
."\r\n"
."--myboundary\r\n"
."Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
."Content-Disposition: form-data\r\n"
."\r\n"
."$data_string\r\n"
."--myboundary\r\n"
."Content-Type:application/pdf\r\n"
."Content-Disposition: file; filename=\”testDS.pdf\"; documentid=1 \r\n"
."\r\n"
."$file_contents\r\n"
."--myboundary--\r\n"
."\r\n";

// *** append "/envelopes" to baseUrl and as signature request endpoint
$curl = curl_init($baseUrl . "/envelopes" );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestBody);                                                                  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=myboundary',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($requestBody),
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )                                                                       
);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ( $status != 201 ) {
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status . "\nerror text is --> ";
    print_r($json_response); echo "\n";
    exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$envelopeId = $response["envelopeId"];

//--- display results
echo "Document is sent! Envelope ID = " . $envelopeId . "\n\n";
```

Is there any possibilities that my integratorkey is not valid? if yes, is there any way for me to check if my integrator key is valid or not? 
In creating my integratorkey i just followed the procedure in this link http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/quick-start/first-api-call

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: Im using XAMPP 1.7.3 with PHP: 5.3.1

Comment: Hmmm, in that case I think it's probably security software or a firewall that's keeping your request from going through.  Are you behind either of these?  If so, can you confirm that your requests are making it through them?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong with the code right away.  Whenever no status is returned at all it's usually one of three things that may be causing this:

1. Security software stopping your request from going through.
2. A Firewall stopping your request from going through.
3. Port 443 being closed for some other reason (other than 2 or 3).

Do you have any logs you can check to see if your requests are being intercepted, either at the software level or hardware level (if you have a hardware firewall)?  I'd start by checking things like that.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Ergin but my 443 port is not blocked. Btw im now using this code `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` before running `curl_exec($curl);` just to avoid the above error. Is there any alternative way aside from using the said code? There could be a possible attack when using the that code right?